# Go to next or previous item if a key does not exist in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What I'm trying to achieve looks quite tricky to me. I want to move from one item to another which I am able to easily achieve with this code snippet as shown below.

Assuming I am having this array of Objects

```
const arr = [
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },  
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
];
```

Then I use this code snippet to achieve moving to the next item which works fine.

```
let count = 0;
arr[count + 1];
return arr
```

However, What I am trying to achieve is move to the next item that doesn't have a `answered: true` key:value Meaning if I'm starting from the 0 index the next button should move to 3rd index because it doesn't have a `answered: true`

For more clarity, If I am able to get items that does not contain `answered` filtered out, I have to be able to do a `count + 1` that can also move me to the next array index in the filtered result.

Assuming the filtered result is

```
const filtered = [
{ duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
]
```

I should be able to do
`filtered[count + 1]`

Thank you

Comment: Your snippet seems to do "nothing". Probably you want `arr.findIndex(e => boolean(e.answered))` to find index for  the first element without `answered: true`

Comment: what triggers the move to the next item that doesn't have `answered = true` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both the iterator and the array are part of a global state, the function `click()` aims to simulate a button click that you mentioned.

The function loops through the array and starts searching for the next unanswered element, starting from the global iter value. The function sets the `iter` to be one after the current element that is not answered, so that when the function is called again, it starts searching from that next element.

The `reset()` function simply restarts the search again from the start.

```js
let iter = 0

const arr = [{
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    duration: 10
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    duration: 3
  },
  {
    duration: 1
  },
];


const findNext = () => {
  for (let i = iter; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!('answered' in arr[i]) || !arr[i].answered) {
      document.getElementById("resultIndex").innerHTML = `Result id: ${i}`;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `Result body: ${JSON.stringify(arr[i])}`;
      iter = i + 1
      return
    }
  }
}

const reset = () => {
  iter = 0
  document.getElementById("resultIndex").innerHTML = `Result id: none`;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = `Result body: none`;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onClick={findNext()}>Next</button>
  <button onClick={reset()}>Reset</button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id='resultIndex'>Result id: none</div>
  <div id='result'>Result body: none</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you @AmehPls.

Can you also help with a snippet function for `findPrev()` this function does the reverse of `findNext()` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array with elements that do not contain `answered`, then loop on them in the normal way.

```js
var index = 0;

const arr = [
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },  
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },  
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
];

function findNext() {
  for (item in arr) {
    if (!arr[item].hasOwnProperty('answered')) {
      document.getElementById("index").setAttribute('value',item);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="findNext()">Find next</button>

<input type="text" value="" id="index">
```

Comment: Actually I was able to get to this part where I can get just the filtered item. But what I need to get fixed is the counter that performs the next.

Imagine the counter starts from 0, count + 1 will increase to 1. So If I have filtered item that is more than 4 It means the counter will jump to the index 1 instead of start from index 0

Comment: I imagine that you are working with some sort of educational portal or Q&A page, where you just scan questions that are not answered one by one and stop on the first question that is not answered, then display a button to ask the user to answer. Is my assumption corrent?

Comment: Ohhhh yes! You are very correct

Comment: Try to see my edit, and run it in code snippet, you can play with the array and set answered as you wish.

Comment: Also try other solutions, there are good ones here, but mine might be more tailored for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
const arr = [
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 },
{ answered: true, duration: 15 },
{ duration: 15 }
]
var i = 0
var missing

for (const element of arr) {
  if (!element.answered) { 
    missing = element
    break
  }
  i++
}

console.log(missing)
console.log(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable function:

```
findKeyValue(arr, 'answered', true)
```

On each object `.flatMap()` array method will compare a given `key` (`"answered"`) and a given `value` (`true`) and returns the index number. It's not very clear as to the nature of this *"button"* so I guessed as to it's purpose and how it was made.

***Details commented in example below***

**Note:** The input array is altered to show functionality better.

```js
const arr = [{
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    answered: true,
    duration: 15
  },
  {
    id: 'x'
  },
  {
    duration: 20,
    id: 'x'
  },
  {
    answered: true
  }
];

// Parameters and counter
let array = arr;
let key = 'answered';
let value = true;
let counter = 0;


function findKeyValue(array, key, value) {
  return array.flatMap((obj, idx) => obj[key] === value ? idx : []);
}

//console.log(findKeyValue(arr, 'answered', true));

//console.log(findKeyValue(arr, 'id', 'x'));

// Event handler binded to button
document.querySelector('button').onclick = incrementSkip;

// Event handler
function incrementSkip(e) {
  // [0,2,5]
  const indices = findKeyValue(array, key, value);
  // <ol> after the <button>
  const list = e.target.nextElementSibling;
  // All <li> of <ol>
  const items = list.children;
/*
items = [<li>,...<li>]
indices = [0,2,5]
counter = 0 index of indices -- next click will be 2
*/
items[indices[counter]].style.background = 'cyan';
  // increment counter by 1
  counter++;
  /*
  if indices length is less than counter then start over at 0
  */
  if (counter > indices.length-1) counter = 0;
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<ol>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>II</li>
  <li>III</li>
  <li>IV</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>VI</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

*If I am able to get items that [do] not contain answered filtered out* ..... **WISH GRANTED**

- `filtered` contains only objects that do not have `answered = true`
- `getNext()` accepts the start index or `count` to use your words, and target array, and returns element of `filtered` at `count+1`
- I notice that your indexing is `1-based` but since array indices are `zero-based` in JavaScript my example sends `-1` so that `count+1` (the first  index) is `0`.

```js
const arr = [
    { answered: true, duration: 15 },  
    { answered: true, duration: 15 },
    { duration: 15 },
    { answered: true, duration: 15 },
    { duration: 15 },
];

const filtered = arr.filter(({answered}) => answered);

//console.log( filtered );

function getNext(startIndex, array) {
     return array[startIndex+1]
}

console.log( getNext(-1, filtered) );
```